# endless marquee

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok I have this html

```
        <marquee scrollamount="6">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" ><img src="images/banner/03.gif" /></a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" ><img src="images/banner/04.gif" /></a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" ><img src="images/banner/05.gif" /></a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" ><img src="images/banner/06.gif" /></a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" ><img src="images/banner/07.gif" /></a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" ><img src="images/banner/03.gif" /></a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" ><img src="images/banner/04.gif" /></a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" ><img src="images/banner/05.gif" /></a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" ><img src="images/banner/06.gif" /></a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" ><img src="images/banner/07.gif" /></a>
        </marquee>
```

this marque moves my images from right to left.

my question is, is there a way to know if the element is hidden already?

I'm planning to get the element that goes out of view then append it as last element of `<marquee>`. I want to get an endless marquee. Please help me, I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jquery + marquee plugin like http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/

`<marquee>` tag is deprecated:

> The marquee tag is a non-standard HTML
>   element which causes text to scroll
>   up, down, left or right automatically.
>   The tag was first introduced in early
>   versions of Microsoft's Internet
>   Explorer, and was compared to
>   Netscape's blink element, as a
>   proprietary non-standard extension to
>   the HTML standard with usability
>   problems. It is deprecated by the W3C
>   and not advised by them for use in any
>   HTML documents.